# URLs amigáveis php

Tags: php, url-amigável

Olá, minha dúvida é a seguinte: Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em HTML e PHP, estive pesquisando sobre URLs amigáveis, alguns amigos me indicaram a  usar porque segundo eles a página principal não seria atualizada cada vez que eu acessar um link. Pois bem, segui muitos tutorias, fiz dezenas de formas diferentes que encontrei na web e acredito não estar funcionando. Para testar estou usando uma função que faz UPDATE em um banco mysql no topo da página, ou seja, cada vez que toda página é atualizada ele acrescenta +1 contando o retorno do banco +1. Gostaria de saber como faço para que quando eu chamar outra página em um link apenas busque o conteúdo e não faça um refresh em toda página

segui este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCnBrQ1fekA

segue o código que fiz:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

config.inc.php

```
<?php
define('HOME', 'http://localhost/testeAmigo/');
define('THEME','paginas');

define('INCLUDE_PATH', HOME.THEME);
define('REQUIRE_PATH',THEME);

$getUrl = strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_DEFAULT)));
$setUrl = (empty($getUrl) ? 'index' : $getUrl);
$Url = explode('/', $setUrl);
//var_dump($Url);
 ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require 'config.inc.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Teste Urls Amigáveis</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="?url=home"> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="?url=contato"> Contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="?url=sobre"> Sobre</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <hr>

  <!--CONTEUDO -->
  <?php
  $Url [1] = (empty($Url[1]) ? null : $Url[1]);
  if(file_exists(REQUIRE_PATH . '/' . $Url[0] . '.php')):
    require REQUIRE_PATH . '/' . $Url[0] . '.php';
    elseif(file_exists(REQUIRE_PATH . '/' . $Url[0] . '/' . $Url[1] . '.php')):
      require REQUIRE_PATH . '/' . $Url[0] . '/' . $Url[1] . '.php';
    else:
      require REQUIRE_PATH . '/404.php';
    endif;
    ?>
    <!--CONTEUDO -->
    <hr>
    <footer>
      <center>
        <label>www.teste123.com</label>
      </center>

    </footer>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Além disso existe a pasta 'pagians' que contem os arquivos home.php, contato,php e sobre.php.

Comment: Você quer atualizar o conteúdo, sem atualizar a página? É isso?

Comment: Sim, por exemplo: Tenho minha estrutura html(index.php) com as chamadas de CSS e JS(tags), no meio da página tenho uma div conteúdo que chama o arquivo conforme eu clicar nos liks do menu, só que cada vez que eu clico em um link ele recarrega toda a página. Me indicaram as URLs amigáveis, mas acho que não seria o ideal para isso.

Comment: Não Rafa, para fazer isso você pode utilizar AJAX do JQUERY. Dá uma pesquisada. Tem bastante conteúdo sobre isso aqui no Stack e também no google.

Comment: Você precisa utilizar javascript ou puro ou com JQUERY, pois ele vai identificar um EVENTO (click) e ai você irá atualizar uma div ou um conteúdo junto com o php. A palavra chave é ajax.

Comment: Vou pesquisar Andrei Muito Obrigado